# Data driven web tests agents does not have unique data

Tags: visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

I tried above solution mentioned in

[Data driven load testing with Visual Studio - where are web tests generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003382/data-driven-load-testing-with-visual-studio-where-are-web-tests-generated/32042421#32042421)

also created plugin and added to solution still I can see my deployment folder in all agent machine contains all the users mentioned in my web test, the users are not distributed among agent and load test failed as every agent used same user to login and access. is there any step missing in above post, if anyone had similar issue please share workaround.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you set the access method for the data source to **Unique** as per the linked question?

Comment: Yes, I set data source access method as Unique

Comment: What does the plugin do? When you run the test is the same data source line used more than once? How many lines are in the data source and how many test cases are executed in total with that data?

Comment: I have 10 Agent and only one performance test run under test mix of load test and have user data of 100 users in .csv file. when I run load test with only one agent then load test is successful, but when I run load test with all 10 Agents then getting concurrency issues as all 10 agents have same copy of .CSV file in deployment folder and try to use same account although i used data source access method as Unique.

Comment: This issue has been resolved, I did following steps it may help someone having issue
01. Created console application which cleanup datasource .csv file and keep only required records
02. Write a batch file  to execute console application exxe
03. Added console application exe and batch file in deployment of .testsettings file property
04. Added batch file in Setup and Cleanup Script as test settings setup script.
05. after this settings Load test execute and copy batch file and application file on each agent and cleanup datasource to get unique accounts to run load test.

Comment: It is good that you problem has been solved. It would be better if you wrote your solution as an answer to this question. The reason is that comments are considered less important than questions and answers. (Also because answers can be neatly formatted but comments are just a lump of text.)