# TFS Visual Studio 2015 Load Test Intranet WebSite Setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

What I am trying to accomplish is run a load of 6000 vUsers on a web page. I cannot figure out how to call the load controllers. I cannot find any clear documentation about what to do next to call my load tests and assign the work to multiple load controllers. Since this is internal to my company. I cannot use VSTS load controllers.

Based on these pages
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/edwinh/2016/04/21/guide-to-get-started-with-visual-studio-web-load-testing-and-automation-2/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn250793(v=vs.120).aspx#Anchor_3

You can install load controllers on other servers. I have done this. 
[image]

I connected to the load controller in the load settings file. But, how would I attached to two or more load controllers?
[image]

I also tried a build test using the solution test settings file. I also don't see a way to attach to many load controllers. If i run the test build it runs.. but i have no info to see if it even ran the test.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load tests that need more resources than can be run directly from Visual Studio can use a controller and some agents. Only one controller can be used for a load test but it can control many agents. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28021907/546871) for a very brief idea of how it works.

Having configured a controller, the agents can be configured. Each agent is configured to work for a specific controller. The `.testsettings` file in the solution names the controller that is to be used for the test. The solution may have multiple `.testsettings` files. The context menu of one of them in solution explorer should have a "tick" against "Active load and web test settings".

Visual Studio 2015 introduced a new scheme where Visual Studio is the only controller for a 2015-Agents. The documentation I have seen is not clear on how to use this 2015-Agent. However, the 2013 versions of both controller and agent can be used with Visual Studio 2015.

One way of seeing whether the load test have run is to look for the test results with Visual Studio. Open any `.loadtest` file, use the `Open and manage results` command and select `<Show results for all tests>`. Should then see all the test runs saved in the database. You would also need to check that the connection string refers to the database used by the controller.

I have not run tests from the TFS build environment, so I cannot comment on how that may affect what happens.

Comment: I figured this out yesterday about the agent and 2013. I did't know about the 2015 VS being the agent. I found a post from MSFT that says use 2013 for load tests. This is an excellent response. Thanks

Comment: Just to correct what you wrote in the comment. VS2015 is the controller, the agents are the computers that execute the tests. VS2015 controls the tests.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install at least 1 agent to connect all the load controllers together.  Specifically if you are running 2015. like I am. You have to install the 2013 Update 5 agents and controllers to make it all work.